# gradle multi-project: build directory appears in root dir containing Kotlin artefacts

Tags: gradle, kotlin

Our multi-project build has the following structure:

`root-project
\-project1
\-project2
\-build.gradle
\-settings.gradle`

When I run a `gradle build` from the root-project directory the build artefacts in project1 (not a Kotlin project) remain under the project1/build directory as expected. However, a build directory appears under the root-directory containing only `build/kotlin` and `build/kotlin-build` directories.

Even if I run `gradle build` from `root-project/project2` I see the same behaviour.

What am I missing to order force all of the kotlin build artefacts to be placed under:

`root-dir/project2/build`

I have the following in my `root-dir/build.gradle` which may be shed some light on the behaviour:

```
    task root-project(dependsOn: ':project1:build') {
       doLast {
           copy {
               from project(':project1:').file('dist')
               into project(':project2:').file('build/resources/main/static/')
           }
       }
    }

    project(':project1') {
        task UI(dependsOn: ':project1:runAll') {
            doLast {
                println 'UI'
            }
        }
    }

    project(':project2') {
        task API(dependsOn: ':project2:bootRun') {
            doLast {
                println 'API'
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resulting artifacts are actually placed under the subproject directories, quite as you expect.

The `build/kotlin` and `build/kotlin-build` directories in the root project contain some internal state that the Kotlin Gradle plugin stores and uses across builds (such as multi-module incremental compilation cache). It's placed under the root project directory, because it is also shared across the subprojects.

In other words, it's not something to worry about.

Comment: Just me then, unnecessary clutter is always something to worry about.  It needs to be added to `.ignore` files, since Gradle doesn't make a build directory for the Root Project.  More stuff to remove before making a `.7z` file.  And also it is possible on occasions when  I want to dump caches, and temp folders one more folder add to the _clean-up list_.  Which is something to deal with because `gradle project2:clean` does Not clean-up the root project `build/` directory.  Basically, I find it untidy.